# Is Laplace's equation valid in presence of point dipole?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law, dipole

In the presence of point dipoles in a region of interest, can I say that the charge density at the dipoles' positions is zero and hence Laplace's equation is valid and can be solved with separation of variables?

Comment: The charge density at the location of a dipole is not zero; you have to use appropriate Dirac deltas, so you're solving Poisson's equation in the distributional sense.

Comment: so for example : "A point dipole p is imbedded at the center of a sphere of linear
dielectric material (with radius R and dielectric constant er). Find the electric potential inside and outside the sphere." Why can I use separation of variables and solve laplace's equation here?

Comment: Yes you can, but you'll need to know how to expand $\partial_z\delta$ in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At any point other than the exact position of the point dipole, the charge density is zero and hence the electric field satisfies the Laplace equation. But keep in mind that this one point makes all the difference! You can't ignore the dipole altogether.

The formal way to write the Poisson equation in such cases is using the Dirac delta distribution. You can first derive the charge density of the point dipole by taking the limit of a normal dipole as the distance $d$ goes to zero:
\begin{align}
\rho(\mathbf{x},t) &= \lim_{d\rightarrow 0} \bigg( \frac{p}{d} \delta(\mathbf{x} + d \hat{\mathbf{n}}/2) - \frac{p}{d} \delta(\mathbf{x} - d \hat{\mathbf{n}}/2) \bigg)\\[5pt]
&= p~\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}\delta(\mathbf{x})\\[5pt]
&= \mathbf{p}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}\delta(\mathbf{x}),
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{p} = p \hat{\mathbf{n}}$ is the dipole moment, and $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\delta(\mathbf{x})$ is the [gradient of the Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives_of_the_Dirac_delta_function) (in the distributional sense).

So the Poisson equation for a single point dipole is
$$\nabla^2\phi(\mathbf{x},t) = - \frac{\mathbf{p}}{\epsilon_0}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla}\delta(\mathbf{x}).$$